# How to padding IconButton with click effect correctly?

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter. And I try to demo app. I need a IconButton on appBar and I create it. But I set padding to IconButon and icon position changed but click wave effect not changed with iconButton.

I want to correctly set padding to IconButton.

Here is my appBar :

```
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Demo App'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.dehaze, size:45.0, ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        tooltip: 'Air it',
        onPressed: (){},
    ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your icon size in `IconButton` widget instead of `Icon`. This way IconButton will recognize the resized icon and do the magic for you.

```
 IconButton(
   iconSize: 45,
   icon: new Icon(Icons.dehaze),
   tooltip: 'Air it',
   onPressed: (){},
 ),
```

Comment: I try it but I set padding it looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1173Z3Lj-MvZUyVX5YqTM2wzoItHnmjKs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you remove padding and alignment from your original code?

Comment: Yes it works. I dont realize gap first time. But what if I want to more padding how I do it ?

Comment: `IconButton` is a Material Design widget and it has its own guidelines, which suggests the minimum button size as 48 and padding as 8 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/8a83d0df7f2eab9d4fb29ca6bef4b7d20070a54e/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icon_button.dart.  You can either take this source code and modify as your needs or use InkWell/GestureDetector widgets.